# How to do a post call and render screen simultaneously in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, wpf

I'm trying to integrate a react screen on a legacy .net wpf application. Our requirement is to open a browser (chrome) on a button click from wpf application. On button click, it will make a post call to react server and render the screen.

We tried using multiple things like implementing cefsharp and that didn't work. We want a quick solution  as of now how can we achieve this ? How can we do a post call and render the url? I would appreciate much if you have c# code available for this.